# Jersey: http error 400

Tags: post, curl, jersey

I need to write a Jersey Client in Spring.

Using CURL, this works:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic aaaaaaabbbbb" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST "http://163.162.8.112:9000/path" --data @TestWrapperJob.json
--> return a STRING

-- TestWrapper.json
{ "name": "job2aad",
 "description": "Descrizione test job1",
 "tests": [ {
   "TestPath": "EsempiRiccardo\\TestWrapper",
   "TestDuration": "2"
  } ],
  "topology": null
}
```

Now I'm trying to translate in JAVA, but i get *HTTP ERROR 400*

```
Client client = Client.create();
String temp = "{ \"name\": \"job2aad\", "
        + " \"description\": \"Descrizione test job1\", "
        + " \"tests\": [ { "
        + "   \"TestPath\": \"EsempiRiccardo\\TestWrapper\", "
        + "   \"TestDuration\": \"2\" "
        + "  } ], "
        + "  \"topology\": null "                   
        + "}";
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://163.162.8.112:9000/path");
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic aaaaaaabbbbb")
     .type("application/json")
        .post(ClientResponse.class, temp);
```

What's wrong?

Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry to all...
I found the answer

```
  + "   \"TestPath\": \"EsempiRiccardo\\TestWrapper\", "
```

should be

```
  + "   \"TestPath\": \"EsempiRiccardo\\\\TestWrapper\", "
```